# Arm inline assembly volatile caused compute result error in clang with asan

Tags: c++, arm, inline-assembly

My question is that I get the wrong result when variables nn has no volatile identifiers, but when I add a volatile identifier to nn, then I get the right result. What's going on when I add the volatile?
My wrong code is below:

```
            int size = outw * outh;
            (volatile)int nn = size >> 2;
            int remain = size & 3;

            float32x4_t _bias0 = bias ? vld1q_f32(&bias[p]) : vdupq_n_f32(0.0f);
            int chanel_offset=in_channel_offset*4;
            int kernel_offset=inch*4;

            if (nn > 0)
            {
                // fprintf(stderr, "%s %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
                asm volatile(
                    "add        r0, %[kernel0], %[kernel_offset]            \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {d0-d3},  [%[kernel0]]                      \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {d4-d7},  [r0]                              \n"
                    "add        r0, r0, %[kernel_offset]                    \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {d8-d11},  [r0]                             \n"
                    "add        r0, r0, %[kernel_offset]                    \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {d12-d15},  [r0]                            \n"

                    "add        r1, %[r0], %[channel_offset]                \n"
                    "pld        [%[r0], #128]                               \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {q13}, [%[r0] :128]!                        \n" // q13 = r0

                    "pld        [r1, #128]                  \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {q14}, [r1 :128]            \n" // q14 = r1

                    "pld        [%[outptr0], #128]          \n"
                    "vdup.32    q9, %e[_bias0][0]           \n"
                    "pld        [%[outptr1], #128]          \n"
                    "vdup.32    q10, %e[_bias0][1]          \n"

                    "0:                                     \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q9, q13, d0[0]              \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q10, q13, d4[0]             \n"
                    "add        r1, r1, %[channel_offset]   \n"
                    "pld        [%[outptr2], #128]          \n"
                    "vdup.32    q11, %f[_bias0][0]          \n"

                    "vmla.f32   q9, q14, d0[1]              \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q10, q14, d4[1]             \n"

                    "pld        [%[outptr3], #128]          \n"
                    "vdup.32    q12, %f[_bias0][1]          \n"

                    "vmla.f32   q11, q13, d8[0]             \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q11, q14, d8[1]             \n"

                    "pld        [r1, #128]                  \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {q15}, [r1 :128]            \n" // q15 = r2

                    "vmla.f32   q12, q13, d12[0]            \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q12, q14, d12[1]            \n"

                    "add        r1, r1, %[channel_offset]   \n"

                    "vmla.f32   q9, q15, d1[0]              \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q10, q15, d5[0]             \n"

                    "pld        [r1, #128]                  \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {q13}, [r1 :128]            \n" // q13 = r3

                    "vmla.f32   q11, q15, d9[0]             \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q12, q15, d13[0]            \n"

                    "add        r1, r1, %[channel_offset]   \n"

                    "vmla.f32   q9, q13, d1[1]              \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q10, q13, d5[1]             \n"

                    "pld        [r1, #128]                  \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {q14}, [r1 :128]            \n" // q14 = r4

                    "vmla.f32   q11, q13, d9[1]             \n"
                    "add        r1, r1, %[channel_offset]   \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q12, q13, d13[1]            \n"

                    "pld        [r1, #128]                  \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {q15}, [r1 :128]            \n" // q15 = r5

                    "vmla.f32   q9, q14, d2[0]              \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q10, q14, d6[0]             \n"

                    "add        r1, r1, %[channel_offset]   \n"

                    "pld        [%[r0], #128]               \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {q13}, [%[r0] :128]         \n" // q13 = r0

                    "vmla.f32   q11, q14, d10[0]            \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q12, q14, d14[0]            \n"

                    "pld        [r1, #128]                  \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {q14}, [r1 :128]            \n" // q14 = r6

                    "vmla.f32   q9, q15, d2[1]              \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q10, q15, d6[1]             \n"

                    "add        r1, r1, %[channel_offset]   \n"

                    "vmla.f32   q11, q15, d10[1]            \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q12, q15, d14[1]            \n"

                    "pld        [r1, #128]                  \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {q15}, [r1 :128]            \n" // q15 = r7

                    "vmla.f32   q9, q14, d3[0]              \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q10, q14, d7[0]             \n"

                    "add        r1, %[r0], %[channel_offset]\n"

                    "vmla.f32   q11, q14, d11[0]            \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q12, q14, d15[0]            \n"

                    "add        %[r0], %[r0], #16           \n"

                    "vmla.f32   q9, q15, d3[1]              \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q10, q15, d7[1]             \n"

                    "pld        [r1, #128]                  \n"
                    "vld1.f32   {q14}, [r1 :128]            \n" // q14 = r1

                    "vst1.f32   {q9}, [%[outptr0] :128]!    \n"
                    "vst1.f32   {q10}, [%[outptr1] :128]!   \n"

                    "vmla.f32   q11, q15, d11[1]            \n"
                    "vmla.f32   q12, q15, d15[1]            \n"

                    "subs       %[nn], #1                   \n"

                    "pld        [%[outptr0], #128]          \n"
                    //"vld1.f32   {q9}, [%0 :128]       \n" // q9 = outptr0
                    "vdup.32    q9, %e[_bias0][0]           \n"

                    "pld        [%[outptr1], #128]           \n"
                    //"vld1.f32   {q10}, [%1 :128]       \n" // q10 = outptr1
                    "vdup.32    q10, %e[_bias0][1]          \n"

                    "vst1.f32   {q11}, [%[outptr2] :128]!   \n"
                    "vst1.f32   {q12}, [%[outptr3] :128]!   \n"

                    "bne        0b                          \n"

                    "sub        %[r0], #16                  \n"

                    : [outptr0] "+r"(outptr0), 
                      [outptr1] "+r"(outptr1), 
                      [outptr2] "+r"(outptr2),
                      [outptr3] "+r"(outptr3), 
                      [r0] "+r"(r0),                          
                      [channel_offset] "+r"(chanel_offset)    

                    : [nn] "r"(nn),                          
                      [kernel0] "r" (kernel0),             
                      [kernel_offset] "r" (kernel_offset),   
                      [_bias0] "w" (_bias0)                 
                    : "cc", "memory", "r0", "r1", "q0", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7",
                      "q9", "q10", "q11", "q12", "q13", "q14", "q15");
            }
```

The code above compute the result outprt0,outptr1,outptr2,outptr3 with input kernel, r0, and bias(kernel * r0 + bias).

Comment: To my knowledge the volatile keyword is simply a flag to the compiler that says "Hey, don't try and optimize this!".

Comment: Is the "asan" in the title a typo for "asm"?  Or do you mean compiling with clang's Address Sanitizer (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html)?

Comment: Yes, I mean clang's Address Sanitizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're modifying an input operand, lying to the compiler**.

`volatile int nn` makes the compiler reload it from memory every time, instead of using the value that's supposed to be still in registers after your `asm` statement which promised the compiler that `[nn] "r" (nn)` was an input (read-only) operand.

But your code has `"subs       %[nn], #1`.

---

**Use a `"+r"` constraint for (a copy of) `nn`.**

```
int nn_tmp = nn;  // the asm destroys this copy
asm ("..."  : [nn] "+r"(nn_tmp) : ...);
```

Or use a dummy output with a matching constraint, like

```
int dummy;
asm ("..." : "=r"(dummy)  : [nn] "0" (nn) : ...);
```

Where the `"0"` is the operand-number of the dummy output.

You *could* save/restore `%[nn]` somehow inside the asm, but that's almost invariably worse than letting the compiler rematerialize `nn` if/when needed.

---

You generally don't need `asm volatile`, unless you're taking pointer inputs and using a `"memory"` clobber so some of the outputs aren't in the constraints as `"=m"` or `[dummy_in_out] "+m"( *(float (*)[]) my_array)` to tell it a whole array or arbitrary size accessed through that pointer is a RMW operand.

In your case a memory clobber is probably easiest, and there's probably little scope for the compiler unrolling around this statement or CSEing multiple runs of it with the same inputs.  Or optimizing it away if all the outputs are unused.

Comment: Just to emphasize what Peter is saying here, the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands) are very clear about this: `**Warning**: Do *not* modify the contents of input-only operands (except for inputs tied to outputs).`

Comment: I agree with your idea, but you confused me with the last idea that "you generally don't need asm volatile". Are there any detail difference between asm volatile and asm, especially in performance.

Comment: @冯剑龙: if it can't optimize away in any cases where the result is unused, or the same input is used twice, then no there's no performance difference.  But using a `memory` clobber can force the compiler to spill/reload things that it didn't otherwise need to, and avoiding *that* is the main benefit of using dummy memory operands.  But that can have a downside too if the compiler uses extra registers to hold the pointers separate from the `"+r"(ptr)` operands.

Comment: @冯剑龙 - The [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Volatile) attempt to give some examples of when you do and don't need to use `volatile`.  It's not typically a question of "performance," since you give the exact asm instructions to use.  But if (for example) the compiler believes that the asm will always produce the same result, it can move the asm outside of a loop and just call it once.  This obviously won't work if the asm might not always produce the exact same output when given the exact same input (think: `rdtsc` for example).

Comment: You are brilliant and I got it. Invalidating all cached values may be suboptimal.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd - I have tried to remove volatile qualifier and got the correct result in Xcode with iPhone 7.

Comment: @冯剑龙: that does *not* prove that it's safe in general.  If you're not sure, keep `volatile` and the `"memory"` clobber.  The only outputs of your function (as far as the compiler knows) are the `"+r"` pointers, not the pointed-to memory.

Comment: @冯剑龙: And BTW, a `"memory"` clobber does *not* invalidate *cache*.  It only invalidates registers that were holding a copy of a variable that the asm might have a pointer to (see "escape analysis": any variable whose address might be held in a global somewhere, or that's pointed to by an operand to the asm.)